# JavaFX Inaccurate Coordinates

Tags: java, javafx

The title is a bit broad but I don't know how to describe this issue in fewer words.

I'm making an application in JavaFX with Scene Builder, the point of this application is to have a list of elements to choose from (whichever element you choose doesn't change anything at the moment since I've been trying to fix this major issue along a few others) and to add to the main area in the middle by pressing the insert button, those elements are draggable once added and this is what it looks like once you add one:
[image]

The header at the top is not part of the main area where those elements will be moved around and so I've made a system that is supposed to stop the draggable pane from intersecting with other Regions of choice.

[image]
The issue I'm having is that this header's coordinates don't align with the shown rectangle, what I mean by that is that in the image above the draggable pane cannot go higher than that, it's stopped from doing that, but it can go and move freely within the area where the header actually is:
[image]

Here's the code I'm using:

Main Class: (This Application uses a Json api thing that I have stored in my project, remove anything that has to do with it such as the Gson Stuff for testing)

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class SkriptDnD extends Application {
    public static TreeMap<String, JsonObject> skriptElements = new TreeMap<>();
    public static TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>> skriptTypeElementNames;

    TreeMap<String, Color> skriptTypeColors;

    {
        try {
            skriptTypeColors = new TreeMap<>() {{
                put("Event", Color.rgb(146, 44, 255));
                put("Expression", Color.rgb(123, 250, 36));
                put("Effect", Color.rgb(36, 136, 250));
                put("Condition", Color.rgb(255, 52, 52));
                put("Type", Color.rgb(255, 184, 30));
                put("Function", Color.rgb(168, 168, 168));
                put("Section", Color.rgb(104, 204, 192));
            }};
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("src/main/resources/me/jake/skriptdnd/skript.json"));
            skriptTypeElementNames = new TreeMap<>();
            JsonArray jsonArray = gson.fromJson(reader, JsonArray.class);
            for (JsonElement element : jsonArray) {
                JsonObject object = element.getAsJsonObject();
                String name = object.get("title").getAsString();
                skriptElements.put(name, object);
                String doc = object.get("syntax_type").getAsString().toLowerCase();
                if (!skriptTypeElementNames.containsKey(doc)) {
                    skriptTypeElementNames.put(doc, new ArrayList<>());
                }
                skriptTypeElementNames.get(doc).add(name);
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            try {
                throw exception;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException{
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());

            String css = getClass().getResource("SkriptDnD.css").toExternalForm();
            scene.getStylesheets().add(css);

            stage.setTitle("SkriptDnD");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setMinHeight(550);
            stage.setMinWidth(800);


            StackPane header = (StackPane) scene.lookup("#header");
            Pane sidebar = (Pane) scene.lookup("#sidebar");


            ComboBox<String> typeComboBox = (ComboBox<String>) scene.lookup("#typeComboBox");
            ObservableList<String> types = typeComboBox.getItems();
            types.add("All");
            types.addAll(skriptTypeColors.keySet());
            typeComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

            ComboBox<String> elementComboBox = (ComboBox<String>) scene.lookup("#elementComboBox");
            elementComboBox.getItems().addAll(skriptElements.keySet());
            elementComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

            Pane canvasPane = (Pane) scene.lookup("#canvasPane");
            canvasPane.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent2 -> {
                Point location = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                int mouseX = location.x;
                int mouseY = location.y;
                Window window = scene.getWindow();
                int windowX = (int) window.getX();
                int windowY = (int) window.getY();
                System.out.print("\n"+new Point(mouseX-windowX,mouseY-windowY));
            });
            Button insertButton = (Button) scene.lookup("#insertButton");
            insertButton.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {
                DragPane elementPane = new DragPane(true);
                elementPane.setTranslateX(300);
                elementPane.setTranslateY(300);
                elementPane.setPrefWidth(100);
                elementPane.setPrefHeight(100);
                elementPane.addIntersects(header);
                System.out.print(Utils.getRectangle(header));
                //elementPane.addIntersects(sidebar);
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(100,100,Color.rgb(100,100,100));
                rectangle.setX(0);
                rectangle.setY(0);
                rectangle.setArcWidth(10);
                rectangle.setArcHeight(10);
                elementPane.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent12 -> {
                    if (mouseEvent12.getButton() == MouseButton.MIDDLE) {
                        canvasPane.getChildren().remove(elementPane);
                    }
                });
                elementPane.getChildren().add(rectangle);
                canvasPane.getChildren().add(elementPane);

            });
            stage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

DragPane Class:

```java
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Window;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DragPane extends Pane {
    public Point lastValid = new Point();
    public Point offset = new Point();
    public ArrayList<Region> intersects = new ArrayList<>();

    public DragPane(boolean draggable) {
        if (draggable) {
            addEventFilter(
                    MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
                    mouseEvent -> {
                        Point location = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                        offset.setLocation(location.x, location.y);
                    }
            );

            setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> {
                Node source = (Node) mouseEvent.getSource();
                Scene scene = source.getScene();
                Window window = scene.getWindow();
                int windowX = (int) window.getX();
                int windowY = (int) window.getY();
                int windowWidth = (int) window.getWidth();
                int windowHeight = (int) window.getHeight();
                Rectangle windowRectangle = new Rectangle(windowX, windowY, windowWidth, windowHeight);
                Point location = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                int mouseX = location.x;
                int mouseY = location.y;
                Point futurePoint = new Point(mouseX - offset.x, mouseY - offset.y);
                if (windowRectangle.contains(location)) {
                    if (Utils.intersects(Utils.offset(this, futurePoint),intersects)) {
                        translate(futurePoint);
                        offset.setLocation(mouseX, mouseY);
                        lastValid.setLocation(futurePoint);
                    } else {
                        Point lastValidXPoint = new Point(futurePoint);
                        lastValidXPoint.x = lastValid.x;
                        Point lastValidYPoint = new Point(futurePoint);
                        lastValidYPoint.y = lastValid.y;
                        if (Utils.intersects(Utils.offset(this, lastValidXPoint),intersects)) {
                            translate(lastValidXPoint);
                        } else if (Utils.intersects(Utils.offset(this, lastValidYPoint),intersects)) {
                            translate(lastValidYPoint);
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void translate(Point point) {
        setTranslateX(getTranslateX() + point.x);
        setTranslateY(getTranslateY() + point.y);
    }

    public void addIntersects(Region region) {
        intersects.add(region);
    }

    public void clearIntersects() {
        intersects.clear();
    }

}
```

Utils Class:

```java
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Utils {
    public static Rectangle getRectangle(Region region) {
        return new Rectangle((int) region.getLayoutX(), (int) region.getLayoutY(), (int) region.getWidth(), (int) region.getHeight());
    }

    public static Rectangle offset(Region region, Point offset) {
        double x = region.getTranslateX()+offset.x;
        double y = region.getTranslateY()+offset.y;
        double w = region.getWidth();
        double h = region.getHeight();
        return new Rectangle((int) x, (int) y, (int) w, (int) h);
    }

    public static boolean intersects(Rectangle rectangle, ArrayList<Region> intersects) {
        return intersects.stream().noneMatch((other) -> Utils.getRectangle(other).intersects(rectangle));
    }

}
```

Controller Class:

```java
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Controller {

    public void typeSelect(ActionEvent event) {
        Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
        Scene scene = source.getScene();
        ComboBox<String> typeComboBox = (ComboBox<String>) scene.lookup("#typeComboBox");
        ComboBox<String> elementComboBox = (ComboBox<String>) scene.lookup("#elementComboBox");
        String selected = typeComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toLowerCase();
        ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        if (Objects.equals(selected, "all")) {
            list.setAll(SkriptDnD.skriptElements.keySet().stream().toList());
        } else {
            list.setAll(SkriptDnD.skriptTypeElementNames.get(selected));
        }
        Collections.sort(list);
        elementComboBox.getItems().setAll(list);
        elementComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    }

    public void elementSelect(ActionEvent event) {

    }
}
```

FXML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Point3D?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="550.0" minWidth="800.0" prefHeight="550.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="me.jake.skriptdnd.Controller">
   <children>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <top>
            <StackPane fx:id="header" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="59.0" prefWidth="800.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <Pane prefHeight="59.0" prefWidth="538.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2c2b2b;">
                     <rotationAxis>
                        <Point3D />
                     </rotationAxis></Pane>
                  <Label fx:id="label1" text="SkriptDnD" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" wrapText="true" StackPane.alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Arial Bold" size="18.0" />
                     </font>
                     <StackPane.margin>
                        <Insets left="40.0" />
                     </StackPane.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT">
                     <children>
                        <Button fx:id="insertButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Insert" textOverrun="CLIP">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets right="20.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Arial Bold" size="12.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Button>
                        <ComboBox fx:id="typeComboBox" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" onAction="#typeSelect" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Type" visibleRowCount="7" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                           <opaqueInsets>
                              <Insets />
                           </opaqueInsets>
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets right="20.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </ComboBox>
                        <ComboBox fx:id="elementComboBox" onAction="#elementSelect" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Element" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                     </children>
                     <opaqueInsets>
                        <Insets />
                     </opaqueInsets>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets right="50.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
            </StackPane>
         </top>
         <left>
            <StackPane prefHeight="491.0" prefWidth="40.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <Pane fx:id="sidebar" prefHeight="491.0" prefWidth="34.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ebebeb; -fx-border-color: #cfcece; -fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-width: 0 1px 0 0;">
                     <children>
                        <ToggleButton layoutX="-3.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="2.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ebebeb;" />
                        <FontIcon iconLiteral="far-arrow-alt-circle-right" iconSize="30" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="30.0" />
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
               </children>
            </StackPane>
         </left>
         <center>
            <Pane fx:id="canvasPane" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </center>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Scene Builder Hierarchy + Preview:
[image]

Comment: we need to see the controller(me.jake.skriptdnd.Controller)...

Comment: It has been added

Comment: Don't mix AWT and JavaFX unnecessarily. There is no need to use `MouseInfo` here; use the appropriate mouse event API from JavaFX. Don't use lookups to access elements defined in the FXML; use controller injection in the usual way.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean with Controller Injection? @James_D

Comment: Just the usual: define fields in the controller with field names matching the `fx:id` from the FXML, and annotate them `@FXML`. Then move all the initialization code that's currently in your `Application` class (which is not where it should be) using (fragile) lookups to the controller's `initialize` method. Any basic FXML tutorial should show you how to do this.

Comment: This is an `FXML` app, yet you got a lot going on in your `Main` class `SkriptDnD`.  The only thing it should be doing is maybe loading data and that data to your controller(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that you use Window to calculate the location.
you need to use always the same X,Y when calculating, for example if you want to do it based on the Scene

```
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Window;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DragPane extends Pane {
    public Point lastValid = new Point();
    public Point current = new Point();
    public ArrayList<Region> intersects = new ArrayList<>();
    public Pane myPane;
    public DragPane(boolean draggable,Pane myPane) {//get the pane to use for calculate location
        this.myPane = myPane;
        if (draggable) {
            addEventFilter(
                    MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
                    mouseEvent -> {
                        Bounds boundsInScene = this.localToScene(this.getBoundsInLocal());
                        current.setLocation(boundsInScene.getMinX(), boundsInScene.getMinY());//use the same place always no where the click is on the shape
                    }
            );

            setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> {
                Bounds boundsInScene = myPane.localToScene(myPane.getBoundsInLocal());
                int windowX = (int) boundsInScene.getMinX();
                int windowY = (int) boundsInScene.getMinY();
                int windowWidth = (int) myPane.getWidth();
                int windowHeight = (int) myPane.getHeight();
                if(mouseEvent.getEventType() != MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED){
                    return;
                }
                int mouseX = (int)mouseEvent.getSceneX() - (int) boundsInScene.getMinX();
                int mouseY = (int)mouseEvent.getSceneY() - (int) boundsInScene.getMinY();
                System.out.println("sx: " + mouseEvent.getSceneX() + " sy: " + mouseEvent.getSceneY());
                System.out.println("x: " + mouseX + " y: " + mouseY);
                System.out.println("cx: " + current.x + " cy: " + current.y);
                int futureX =  mouseX;
                int futureY =  mouseY;
                if(futureX + getWidth()/2 < windowX || futureX > windowWidth){
                    futureX = 0; //todo: take care of futureX > windowWidth
                }
                if(futureY + getHeight()/2 < windowY || futureY > windowHeight){
                    futureY = 0; //todo: take care of futureY > windowHeight
                }
                Point futurePoint = new Point(futureX, futureY);
                translate(futurePoint);
                current.setLocation(futureX, futureY);
            });
        }
    }

    public void translate(Point point) {
        setTranslateX(point.x); //this is by Scene - 0 is in myPane.boundsInScene.getMinX()
        setTranslateY(point.y); //this is by Scene - 0 is in myPane.boundsInScene.getMinY()
    }

    public void addIntersects(Region region) {
        intersects.add(region);
    }

    public void clearIntersects() {
        intersects.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: I've implemented this into what I already had, thanks a lot!